# Renaming files with numbers

Tags: files, terminal

I have files:

```
file1
file2 
file3
...
```

How to rename them to

```
file501
file502
file503
....
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L stack exchange. I suggest you take the [tour] and review the help center topics on [how to ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You should then consider editing your question for further details of what you have tried, what has not worked, and what a successful outcome would look like. You have not given us much context. As you see in answer from @Abigail they presume you want to automate this, via a shell script or similar. On the other hand, my answer assumes you do not understand how to use the file management command line utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -wE 'for (@ARGV) {rename $_ => s/\d+/500 + $&/re or die $!}' file*
```

This loops over each filename, calculates the new file name by adding 500 to the numeric part and then renames the file.

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to rename a file in UNIX and Linux systems is with the `rename` or `mv` commands.

These are pretty basic commands and can be explained much better by reviewing the man-pages or other official documentation.

Comment: Just run 'man mv'